# When in {country}, do as the {countrians} do

Tags: code-golf, string, natural-language

(or: Output the plural demonym.)

When in Rome, do as the Romans do. This is a well-known English phrase meaning that it’s best to follow what others are doing around you — to go with the flow. Today, you're going to rewrite the phrase to fit most (Western) place names.

To get the name of a group that lives within a region, there are a couple of cases:

- If the name ends with an ‘i’, ‘o’, or ‘u’, append ‘ans’. If the name ends with an ‘e’ or ’a’, drop it and append ’ans’.
- If the name ends with a ‘y’, replace it with an ’i’ if the preceding character is a consonant, and finally append ‘ans‘.
- If the name ends in a consonant (excluding ‘y’), append ‘ians’.

Some examples:

- “Italy” ends with a consonant followed by a ‘y’, so we replace the ‘y’ with an ‘i’ and append ‘ans’ to get “Italians”.
- “Rome” ends with an ‘e’, so we drop it and append ‘ans’ to get “Romans”.
- “Hungary” → “Hungarians”
- ”Paraguay” → “Paraguayans”.

So, your task is: Given a name starting with an uppercase letter and ending with a lowercase letter, output the name of that group of people.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code per language wins! Defaults for code-golf apply.

### Test cases:

When in Rome, do as the Romans do.

When in Transylvania, do as the Transylvanians do.

When in Code Golf, do as the Code Golfians do.

When in Hawaii, do as the Hawaiians do.

When in Sparta, do as the Spartans do.

When in America, do as the Americans do.

When in South Dakota, do as the South Dakotans do.

When in Korea, do as the Koreans do.

When in India, do as the Indians do.

(And yes, I know there are plenty of outliers, e.g. group names ending in ‘stani’, ‘ese’, ‘er’, etc. However, this formula seems to work for many English place names.)

Comment: Too bad for Chileans :(

Comment: Germanians ?? hmmm.

Comment: "fit most (Western) place names.". Most European countries don't even fit including Spain, Portugal, Germany, France, Netherlands, Norway, Sweden, Denmark, Poland, England, Ireland

Comment: @Ivo Europe doesn't exist in my imagination

Comment: Dominican Republic? xD

Comment: @noodleman and other parts? Japanians and Chinaians ? Philippinesians? Neu Zealandians? Congoans? Israelians?    Singaporeians ? Thailandians ?   Demonyms are quite varied.

Comment: Heck, the US's nearest neighbors, the Canadans...

Comment: "However, this formula seems to work for many English place names." Apart from England, Scotland, Wales, Ireland... :D

Comment: An interesting followup to this might be to reproduce all conversions from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demonym, perhaps scoring by some formula like (codeLength/correctDemonymQuantity)

Comment: @wnoise Finally, something that the Canadans, United Statesians, and Mexicoans can all agree on!

Comment: So not like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hsqx5.jpg)?

Comment: Too bad we can't access a demonym dictionary API or something like that.

Answer (score 9):

## [Lexurgy](https://www.lexurgy.com/sc), <s>72</s> 65 bytes

```
y:
{y,*}=>i/!{a,e,i,o,u,y} _ $
a:
{e,a}=>ans/_ $
Else: *=>ans/_ $
```

Expects input as just the country name, and outputs the plural demonym.

Requires that spaces in the input be replaced with some non-space character due to how Lexurgy processes spaces.

- -7 bytes by @SuperStomer by using `else`

Used test cases:

```
Italy
Rome
Hungary
Paraguay
Transylvania
Code_Golf
Hawaii
Sparta
America
South_Dakota
Korea
India
Noodle
Noodly
Noodley
Ay
By
Aby
Bay
Ohio
```

Comment: Right tool for the job?

Comment: [65 bytes](https://paste.gg/p/anonymous/3f5d890d401b4970870af1a8f7fd22aa)

Answer (score 8):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 40 bytes

```
{_[-~0 3'a;x],(0<a:"yeaiou"?*|x)_"ians"}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJwljMsKwjAURPf5inA3bX1AwV0riCioiCDWnYhc2lSDba7ERFt8fLsm3Z0zM0yZvE6H4TfmowDT5jgI4zEm0AqUZGHSezfRCSSqO3wYM0kIO6oFpBz2+h+21QOVROczKgRfUFU6WeITpXSU3VAbP5jWQsvcY0bWXPgcr9RVa9LCw0oV3dtGNDInf2XVGXXrcCu0hYixfmjSMjDRD9rRN+M=)

Comment: An explanation would be nice for those of us who don’t speak K, but don’t feel obliged to add one

Answer (score 7):

## sed, 35 bytes

Using sed with extended regexes:

`s/([^aeiouy])y?$/\1i/;s/[ea]?$/ans/`

Comment: Note that this is exactly the same as Neil’s Retina answer. Maybe edit that into the post? Just a thought

Answer (score 6):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 31 bytes

```
([^aeiouy])y?$
$1i
r`[ea]?$
ans
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcrBCoJAEIfx@zyFBwM79gQRBSpdIruJ4Z@cbFB3Ytot9uk3j9@Pz9iLQ9oUZZ@K9g4WDbHbxn1O@U7I@pbRrQH3San2mCNddWGqghthkS4wjAGRbrYucf7CCeioA2elzk@q8IMINW@YBx0WNnmAGg3@lZ0w6YpnNQbVbhD8AQ) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
([^aeiouy])y?$
$1i
```

Add `i`s after trailing consonants and replace consonant + `y` with consonant + `i`.

```
r`[ea]?$
ans
```

Remove any trailing `e` or `a` and append `ans`. The `` r` `` is needed to prevent a second empty match after removing the trailing `e` or `a`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 38 bytes

```
Ｐ←⮌ＳＭ⁼ＫＫy←¿№aeiouＫＫＭⅈ←«→Ｐi»Ｍ¬№aeＫＫ→ans
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY5NC4JAEIbP@SuWPc2C/QE7RocgQ@zSdZBRlxbX9kOQ6LdvkxJ5mcM77/PMND26xqJJqYwm6NHpIUBxoTbkoqaJnCc4D2MMt8CrDpRSh6y0E8HpGdF4qIgeoHIhZ8lzIbmhWwFHG9klkbSNMhdrUSmx0HfYtMl4Eq9st2yKWnf9N91tPpJacvJeL19t@Ms3Zhb@2GqlcPDMpVShwy7inPaT@QA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｐ←⮌Ｓ
```

Write the input to the canvas, but with the last letter under the cursor and the first letter to the left.

```
Ｍ⁼ＫＫy←
```

Move left if the last letter is a `y`.

```
¿№aeiouＫＫ
```

If the (previous) letter is a vowel, then...

```
Ｍⅈ←
```

... move back to the last letter, otherwise...

```
«→Ｐi»
```

... move right and place an `i`, which either overwrites a trailing `y` or appends if there was no trailing `y`.

```
Ｍ¬№aeＫＫ→
```

Move right unless the last letter is an `a` or an `e`.

```
ans
```

Overwrite the `a` or `e` with `ans` or append `ans` otherwise.

Comment: Clever use of the canvas! Didn’t expect a solution like this.

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 33 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
žPSD'y«s„aeS)vDyÅ¿àiNi'i«ë¨]…ans«
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##AUEAvv9vc2FiaWX//8W@UFNEJ3nCq3PigJ5hZVMpdkR5w4XCv8OgaU5pJ2nCq8Orwqhd4oCmYW5zwqv//0NvZGUgR29sZg) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##JYzBasJAEIZfZZmLCOIrBDHQSkHFiD0UD1OzmsG4I7tJZG9eim8hPZVC3qHCpr6ILxKTzWm@@Wf@jw1@kqwLeE@kEqQEBDaAgYhZoBFZItsA6vvfPAp71pXmcb6ijPr/F1OEtvpyt@qbptQjV1al@10/zj@ojCtrGK4CaDRDGNQfMMkwtY0WFnyQ7XzN1Q61j@aocZej56Vu2jYtUBG2@5hjKV443foOnpCopeiIOvMPo4PUtPEYcZ4lIsQ9d6c31tLDRMWdbZYQw/oJ).

**Explanation:**

```python
žP              # Push all consonants (minus "y")
  S             # as a list of characters
D'y«           '# Duplicate it, and append an "y" to each consonant
    s           # Then swap so the consonant-list is at the top again
„aeS            # Push pair ["a","e"]
)               # Wrap all three items on the stack into a list
 v              # Pop and loop over this triplet of lists:
  D             #  Duplicate the current string
                #  (which will be the implicit input in the first iteration)
       i        #  If
    Å¿          #  the current string ends with
      à         #  any of the items of
   y            #  the current list of the loop:
        Ni      #   If this is the second iteration (the 0-based index is 1):
          'i«  '#    Append an "i" to the string
         ë      #   Else (index is 0 or 2):
          ¨     #    Remove the last character instead
 ]              # Close both the if-else statement and loop
  …ans«         # Append string "ans"
                # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 119 bytes

-5 bytes thanks to `noodle man`.

```python
lambda c,v='iouea',s='ans':(((c+'i'+s,(k:=c[:-1])+'iy'[c[-2]in v]+s)['y'==(l:=c[-1])],k+s)[l in v[3:]],c+s)[l in v[:3]]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=TY8xTsQwEEV7TuFuHMUpYBsUKQVaClY0iEWiCC4GJ9lYcezIcbKyVpyEJhKC03ABbsM6SbHTzJ83X-Pvz5_Ou9ro6avK3r4HVyW3f0eF7XuBRLAxA2mGEoH1GaDuIaWUihgkxD2jTZqJPE2ueXQmHnKRJzdcajLyuI9y8JBlVAVPsHDWBKpIMOSblHMmLkC64Xx9_rcylggzaGd9WObwbNoSGIEXe87g1YhaYpi3pijJ1qgqDA94RCmD2ndo3Wy4a0srxSz3ZnA1ucfGLKtHY8tZ7HSxXNs5VH6-NOgD2lk-ocXDgB54ekXO1VmpHa3gtS51yHZac36QwhDsyamiK4kCgmj50zQt_R8)

Comment: You can save five bytes by indexing into `'iy'` instead of `('i','y')`

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (SpiderMonkey)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey/Releases/45), 96 bytes

```javascript
x=>((p=[...x])[l=x.length-1]=`${"iou"[c="contains"](r=p[l])?r:!"ae"[c](r)?"i":""}ans`)&&p.join``
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY89a8MwFEX3/gr1UYI0RKFrQPXSod1CpoAx@FlRZKWyJPSROpT@dlddOhSv59wL917xhklGE/I2BXNWcfLuQ92Xi1hm8UJpEC3nfO5Ya8XMrXI6j9vnTvRPX2B8gVYKkN5lNC5BR6MIre1YE/ePgKrailgDBvYA3@hSzzabwK/euL5fai95q7j1ml4oHP2kgLGHf/g9o72v8LfiNMY1c8CIuuCaevWTcUaiI0cVymCNrCGy25ETP5E0@mLPZFB/si4mQ8lEjmh/vytiEvmM3ulm@QE)

Comment: Using the regex from the Retina/sed answers would be 60 bytes: `s=>s.replace(/([^aeiouy])y?$/,"$1i").replace(/[ea]?$/,"ans")`

Comment: @corvus_192 yeah, regex make it shorter but I didnt wanted to use it tbh

Answer (score 2):

## [Python](https://python.org) >= 3.8, 173 bytes

```
import re
lambda k:any((l:=re.subn(a,b,k))[1]for a,b in map(lambda m:f'({m}ans'.split('|'),(r'\w[iou])$|\1',r'\w)[ea]$|\1',r'[aeiou]y)$|\1',r'[^aeiou])y$|\1i','$)|i')))*l[0]
```

`any` stops iterating after the first truthy result (in this case, when `subn` replaces at least 1 time)

[ATO!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=PZHPTgIxEMbvPEUPJtOahcjNbIKJwYPEixFvZU0GaKGhfzallTTAk3jhondfwPfwbaS7iz19v_mmk28yH191CmtnT6fPGGT_9vdbmdr5QLzoSTIiGs18iWRTok2U6nLkxWAb55ZiMS82jPFhJZ0nZyLKEoM17X6YUgLdmyPaLQy2tVaBwgFYQT3Mdly5WLGrw2wIRWbGBVYX5Ciynf59_tZWWMoVBQVcsYMCxti15jdVF_wn51i4aINPOQuHF2cEFARe_TlE0u9oFWYeu6UgY6dlhkfcoVJZTWv0oWm4N8KrRSOnLoY1ecCNa60n50UjJnbZTpsE1KmZFO0KfSOf0eMqYoKq7JHzq72ygUrYd_mOpH9H9pJ2yI7A2i0uZ_gD) (`f =`  added to run test cases)

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice answer! By the way, you can put the import after the lambda and put `f=\` in the header: [ATO](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=PY_PSgMxEMbvfYochElkW-xNFipIPVi8iPWWrjBtkzY0f5Y0sYS2T-KlIHrzFXwP38ZmdzWX-X7zZYZv3j7rFNbOnt7laPYRg-xf_3xpNPMlkk2JNlGqy5EXg22cW4rFvNgwxoeVdJ6ciShLDNa0mzClBLo3R7RbGGxrrQKFA7CCepjtuHKxYheH2RCKzIwLrP6Qo8h2-vf5S9thKXcUFHDBDgoYY5eaX1U9ZWrnA_GiC_2dEy1ctMGnnIrDkzMCCgLP_hwn6Ve0CjOP3VKQsdMywz3uUKmspjX60Hy4NcKrRSOnLoY1ucONa60H50UjJnbZbpsE1KnZFO0KfSMf0eMqYoKq7JHzq72ygUrYd_mOpH9D9pJ2yI7A2itOp7b-Ag)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `Ṫ`, 186 [bits<sup>v2</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 23.25 bytes

```
÷‛aeF:\y=¨iȮ:\o+Ah¬\i*`□⟑
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyLhuapBPSIsIiIsIsO34oCbYWVGOlxceT3CqGnIrjpcXG8rQWjCrFxcaSpg4pah4p+RIiwiIiwiUm9tZVxuVHJhbnN5bHZhbmlhXG5Db2RlIEdvbGZcbkhhd2FpaVxuU3BhcnRhXG5BbWVyaWNhXG5Tb3V0aCBEYWtvdGFcbktvcmVhXG5JbmRpYVxuRWdnIl0=)